# Edit property of a child using REST Api

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a dataset uploaded in following form:

```
SomeKey

 -> Alphabet

       -Emp1: "{ 'Fname' : 'Bob', 'Lname' : 'Sob' }"
       -Emp2: "{ 'Fname' : 'Tom', 'Lname' : 'Mot }"
```

Now using Rest API, I want to edit `Fname` and `Lname` of employee with key `Emp1` to `Fred` and `Dref`, and `Fname` and `Lname` of employee with key `Emp2` to `Kent` and `Tenk` in one single call. Is this possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to update a single employee, you can do so with a PUT REST API call like this:

```
curl -X PUT -d <data> https://some.url.com/SomeKey/Employees/Emp1/.json
```

If would like to update multiple employees using a single REST API call, you can do so with a PATCH REST call like this:

```
curl -X PUT -d '{"Emp1":<data1>,"Emp2":<data2>"}' \
    https://some.url.com/SomeKey/Employees/.json
```

Additional details about the REST API are available here:
https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest-api.html