# How to add custom key for firebase realtime database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

How to add custom key for firebase realtime database? I'm using react native fetch api to connect with database.

```
fetch('https://chld-43c34.firebaseio.com/players.json?auth='+token,{
            method: 'POST',         
            body: JSON.stringify( playerData,)     
            }
```

I have user id in a variable 'userId',want to add that as the key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `method: 'POST'` the database generates a unique child key for you. To instead write the data directly to the location you specify, use `method: 'PUT'` and pass the exact location in the URL:

```
let playerid = 'your_player_id';
fetch(`https://chld-43c34.firebaseio.com/players/${playerid}.json?auth=${token}`,{
    method: 'PUT',         
    body: JSON.stringify( playerData,)     
}
```

Also see:

- [Saving data to Firebase with REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29355596/saving-data-to-firebase-with-rest)
- [C# Firebase Restful Post generate unique key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52139789/c-sharp-firebase-restful-post-generate-unique-key)
- [Edit property of a child using REST Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902360/edit-property-of-a-child-using-rest-api)